# Extjs 4.0 Combo box for a remote query not displaying. The Drop down values show blank description

Tags: php, extjs4

I am trying to upgrade from Extjs 3.4 to Extjs 4.0

```
initComponent: function() {
  this.items = [{
           xtype: 'fieldset',
           width: 600,
           bodyPadding: 40,
           title: 'Dates',
           items: [{
             xtype: 'datefield',
             anchor: '100%',
             fieldLabel: 'From',
             name: 'from_date',
             format: 'm d Y',
             value: '02 04 1978'
           }, {
             xtype: 'datefield',
             anchor: '100%',
             fieldLabel: 'To',
             name: 'to_date',
             format: 'm d Y',
             altFormats: 'm,d,Y|m.d.Y',
             value: '02.04.1978'
           },{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    hiddenName: 'status',
                    fieldLabel: 'Status',
                    store: autoCompleteStore,
                    queryMode: 'remote',
                    forceSelection:'true',
                    triggerAction:'all',
                    displayField:'displayField',
                    fireEventOnSetValue: false,
                    valueField:'valueField',
                    emptyText:'Select one'
              }]
         }]

}

Ext.define("test.Tickler",{
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'f_uid', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'f_description', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'f_value', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'f_visible', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'f_order', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'f_default', type: 'string'},
   ]
  });

var autoCompleteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   model: "test.Tickler",
   proxy:{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '../medit_2_public/fc.php?_C_A=TicklerReport.getListOfTicklerReasons',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
       type: 'json',
       root: 'results.rows',
       metaProperty: 'metaData'
     })
    }
   }

 });
```

Here is my output from metadata:
[,…]
0: {f_uid: "1", f_description: "Needs Form", f_value: "1", f_visible: "Y", f_order: "1", f_default: "N"}
1: {f_uid: "3", f_description: "Call Client", f_value: "2", f_visible: "Y", f_order: "2", f_default: "N"}

When my screen renders I do see Select One in the value of the drop down for Status.  When I select the Drop down I do see the loading warning and I see couple blanks after it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `combobox` definition you have to set which fields from your data should be used in the combobox as **value and display field**. Currently you have set field names that do not exist in your model. For example setup like this:

```
valueField: 'f_value',
displayField: 'f_description'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had a feeling it was an easy fix.